# Data structure with constant time operations

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I need to use a data structure, implementable in C++, that can do basic operations, such as lookup, insertion and deletion, in constant time. I, however, also need to be able to find the maximum value in constant time.

This data structure should probably be sorted to find the maximum values and I have looked into red-black trees, however they have logarithmic-time operations.

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ You won't find something that does everythign in constant time.... log n, or n log n are probably what you want to find where constant time isn't possible.

Comment: Yes I would like to [have my cake and eat it as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can%27t_have_your_cake_and_eat_it).

Answer (score 0):

I would propose

1. You could use a hash table which gives O(1) expected time
2. Regarding the maximum, you could store it in attribute and be aware at each insertion if the maximum changes. With the deletion is some more complicated because if the maximum is deleted, then you must perform a linear search, but this only would happen if the maximum is deleted. Any other element could be deleted in O(1) expected time

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with Irleon.You can use a hash table to perform these operations.Let us analyze this step by step:
1.If we take arrays,the time complexity of insertion will be O(1) at the end.
2.Take linked lists and it will be O(n) due to the traversal that you need to do.
3.Take binary search trees and it will be O(logn) where logn is the height of the tree.
4.Now we can use hash tables.We know that it works on keys and values.So,here the key will be 'number_to_be_inserted % n' where 'n' is the number of elements we have.

But as the list grows on the same index,you will be needing to traverse the list.So it will O(numbers_at_that_index).
Same will be the case in deletion operation.
Ofcourse there are other cases to consider in case of collisions ,but we can ignore that for now and we will get our basic hash table.

Answer (score 0):

If you could do such a thing, then you could sort in linear time: simply insert all of your items, then, do the following n times:

1. Find maximum
2. Print maximum
3. Delete maximum

Therefore, in a model of computation in which you can't sort in linear time, you also can't solve your problem with all operations in O(1) time.